# how built-in function work in php?

Tags: php, function, built-in

We know that Variables in php can get 1 value at the same time and if we want multi value , we must use Array
but when we use for instance :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "chat_php");
```

$conn must get multi value at a same time

my question is:
Is that true if we think that this built-in function -eg mysqli_connect()- convert (or something like that) the $conn variable to an array and put their result therein ?

Comment: `$conn` will be a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) if the connection was successful, when you mean this

Comment: `mysqli_connect` doesn't convert `$conn` - it doesn't even touch it or know about its existance. The function only returns a `pointer` (to a String, to an Array etc.). In the next step, the `$conn` variable is then set (or initialized) to the pointer. But this isn't done by the function; this is done by the PHP runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not actually *storing* inside `$conn` the values you pass as parameters. It merely *uses* those parameters to do something (opening a connection to a database, in that case). You can think of the returned value as something that *references* the open database connection, but it does not *contain* the parameters you passed to `mysqli_connect`. They are not even necessarily stored anywhere.